# whitenoise with zappa, push static files to s3?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, static-content

I am using [WhiteNoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) with [Zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa).

Zappa suggests to keep project sizes down as size will:

> ...eat into the memory space of your application function ([source](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa#large-projects))

Indeed with projects over 50MB you need to set slim_handler=true, which has a slight performance loss.

WhiteNoise advises having your static files on your server, and for eg Amazon Cloudfront to access and cache these.

The cache-22 here is that the many versions of the compresed WhiteNoise static files that are created can lead to static packages > 100MB (in my case).

I dont know how to proceed here. The options are:

- manually push WhiteNoise's static content to an S3 bucket and have Cloudfront have this as an origin, and dont upload the 100MB to Amazon Lambda.
- see if I can get Zappa to bundle out static content to S3 (and remove the static content from the app itself). As Zappa uploads a Zip, perhaps this is a speedier option.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: This is a good question. Part of the problem is that Django keeps both the hashed and the non-hashed versions of the files in STATIC_ROOT. On top of that you have the original files in STATICFILES_DIRS, so you have at least three copies, plus compressed versions. I'll look into ways to mitigate this in the upcoming WhiteNoise release. It might also be possible to do some post-packaging cleanup by defining a ZIP callback in Zappa but I haven't looked into the detail of this.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Zappa-django-guide](https://github.com/edgarroman/zappa-django-guide), I moved over to using django-storages ([tutorial setting up with zappa](https://edgarroman.github.io/zappa-django-guide/walk_static/)).

Whilst I did manage to get WhiteNoise to work with Zappa, our app was very slow. The django-storages solution is zippy!

Comment: Glad you've found something that works. Were you running WhiteNoise behind a CDN (e.g. cloudfront or cloudflare)? That's the recommended way for production setups and should give you better than S3 performance.

Comment: yep. Cloudfront on top of Lambda via whiteNoise. I suspect that with the right caching settings, Whitenoise would work really well. I failed to get this right though (for some reason, Cloudfront was always reaching down into Lambda for my static content).